# Capacitor Matching Ratios - IC Design

Tags: capacitor

[image]

[Marcel Pelgrom's Analog to Digital Conversion]

Hi,
I came across this section under the "Accuracy" chapter and I'm having a hard time grasping what point he is trying to get across here?

Is he suggesting that all my capacitors should be a 4.5:1 ratio? Or that if I make two capacitors and one is 4.5 times the size of the other that I should make each parameter 4.5 times larger, area, perimeter, etc?

Apologies for this question, just having a hard time figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

The 4.5:1 ratio is created by using 12 capacitors (one of which is a dummy) and wiring them in a 9:2 configuration.

By using a square or almost square array of exactly similar unit capacitors accuracy is improved compared to trying to vary the dimensions of the capacitors.

I agree the markings on the capacitors are a bit misleading. The 4.5 refers to the 9 capacitors that are in parallel and the 1 to the two capacitors that are in parallel to yield the (arbitrary example) 4.5:1 ratio.